# Update p text without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a paragraph:

```
 <div id="id1"><span></span><p id="id-text">Starting text</p></div>
```

Now when contact is made with a server (via ajax), following function is called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fun = function (serverIsOk) {
        $('#id-text').innerHTML = serverIsOk ? 'Server ok text' : 'Starting text';
        $('#id1').show();           
}; 
</script>
```

The function is being called, but for some reason the text is not updated though. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.text()` or `.html()`,

```
var response = serverIsOk ? 'Server ok text' : 'Starting text';
$('#id-text').text(response);
```

**OR**

```
var response = serverIsOk ? 'Server ok text' : 'Starting text';
$('#id-text').html(response);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `innerHTML` property in jQuery object, use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead:

```
$("#id-text").html(serverIsOk ? "Server ok text" : "Starting text");
```

Answer (score 2):

`.innerHTML` is no property which gets abstracted by jQuery nor *jQuery objects*. You either have to use the `.html()` function or access the underlaying *DOM node* like

```
$('#id-text')[ 0 ].innerHTML = serverIsOk ? 'Server ok text' : 'Starting text';
```

alternatively, use jQuerys `.html()` method like

```
$('#id-text').html(serverIsOk ? 'Server ok text' : 'Starting text');
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$('#id-text')[0].innerHTML =
```

or

```
$('#id-text').html()
```